# Azure Cosmos DB input binding for Azure Functions when partition key is Partition.None

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmos collection that will contain less than 10 documents, this collection does not have a partition key. So when accessing throw cosmos container, I use `PartitionKey.None` and it works perfectly.

Now I need to bind an Azure Function to this collection:

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction"))]
public async Task Run(
[ServiceBusTrigger("TopicName","TopicSubscription","ServiceBusConnectionStringKey")] MyEvent inputEvent,           
[CosmosDB("databaseName","collectionName","ConnectionString", Id = "{ColorId}", PartitionKey = "")] Color color)
{
    //Do things
}
```

Even when the collection does not have partition key I cant bind without one, I get this error

> PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation

I would like to know if there is any way to put the `PartitionKey.None` or similar on the binding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the partition key to `Undefined.Value` (similar to when setting to `new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value)` within `RequestOptions`)?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I need a constant string to put on the binding, ```Undefined.Value``` is not. I dont see how this will help. If you can write any example please.

Comment: The problem here is that Function bindings have the restriction of the type of values as you mentioned. You can always pulls the DocumentClient instance and run the query manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=csharp#http-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-documentclient-c